# Django deployment, how change path of uploaded images by admin

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my site to pythonanywhere and everything works fine except image saving from admin panel. In my local env everything works fine and uploaded images land in a static folder, but on pythonanywhere they are saved in a different location. That's my code and configs:

**models.py**

```
def generate_filename(self, filename):
    url = "static/galeria/rosliny/%d/%s" % (int(self.nazwa_polska.id_rosliny), filename)
    return url

image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=generate_filename)
```

**my web urls configuration for static(pythonanywhere):**

```
/static/     -  /home/pepikfest/zielnik_karpacki/static
```

files are saving into /home/pepikfes/static/, they miss zielnik_karpacki folder, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in settings.py you have to define the static URL... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: i have sth like this STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/pepikfest/zielnik_karpacki/static'

Comment: Maybe using the command `django-admin collectstatic` the will be moved in static directory.

Comment: django-admin collectstatic moved evething to static, but new uploaded files lands in /home/pepikfes/static/

Comment: static folder is for javascript and this stuff, media folder is fro user uploads. What is your value in settings.py for `MEDIA_ROOT`?